# Add suggested data to a SearchView from a web service

Tags: android, web-services, searchview

I want to add a SearchView in my android app, and I want to suggested devices in this way:

http://queforum.com/android-applications/182251-android-how-build-gmail-like-search-box-action-bar.html

Also, I get JSON data to fill out the list from an own web service.

How can I do that? Because I've been looking for Internet and I've seen that I need a ContentProvider an a SQLite database to do it, and I'm not sure how to do it. I've only created a SearchableActivity.

SearchableActivity.java:

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity implements IWebServiceTaskResult{

/**
 * 
 * */
private ListView listSuggestedDevices;
/**
 * 
 * */
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 
/**
 * 
 * */
private List<String> suggestedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
/**
 * 
 * */
private static String GET_SUGGESTED_DEVICES_SERVICE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
    setServiceDirections();

}

/**
 * 
 * */
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);      
    System.out.println("PASA onNewIntent");
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

/**
 * 
 * */
private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    System.out.println("PASA handleIntent");
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(query);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * */
private void doSearch(String query){
    listSuggestedDevices = getListView();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, suggestedDevices);
    listSuggestedDevices.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (isNetworkAvailable()){
        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this);
        wst.addNameValuePair("query", query);
        wst.execute(GET_SUGGESTED_DEVICES_SERVICE);
    }

}

@Override
public void handleResponse(String response) {
    System.out.println(response);
    JSONObject jso = null;
    if (!response.equals("null")){
        try {
            jso = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jso.has("status")){
                return;
            }

            doAutoComplete(jso);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public Context getContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this;
}

/**
 * 
 * */
private void doAutoComplete(JSONObject jso){
    suggestedDevices.clear();

    Object obj;
    try {
        obj = jso.get("smartphonesList");

        if (obj != null) {
            if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray smartphones = jso.getJSONArray("smartphonesList");
                for (int i = 0; i < smartphones.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject smartphone = new JSONObject(smartphones.getString(i));
                    if (!smartphone.getString("model").equals("")) {
                        suggestedDevices.add(smartphone.getString("model"));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (!jso.getString("smartphonesList").equals("")){
                    JSONObject smartphone = new JSONObject(jso.getString("smartphonesList"));
                    suggestedDevices.add(smartphone.getString("model"));
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
/**
 * 
 * */
private void configureSearchView(Menu menu){
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.searchView));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="findyourdevice.activities.CompareActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name="findyourdevice.activities.SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

If you need more source code, just ask for me.

Thank you!!

Comment: use SearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter, you can use the CursorAdapter similar to one from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara

Comment: Thanks pskink, but one question. This solution is only for MainActivity.java (in this case) or for the whole app? Because I want to search in whole app